# How can I jump to a particular window, no matter what workspace it's on?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-management, i3

Ideally I could say <kbd>$mod</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> → jump to Emacs (wherever it is), and the same could be done for <kbd>$mod</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> → jump to Firefox (wherever it is).

It seems pretty trivial to jump to a workspace, using `workspace 3` or some variant, but going to a particular window is not as obvious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bindsym $mod+j+f [class=Firefox] focus
bindsym $mod+j+e [class=Emacs] focus
```

You can get the `class` argument for any currently window with the following command:

```
xprop -name <window title> | grep WM_CLASS
```

This will return something like

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "emacs", "Emacs"
```

The second string, here `Emacs` is the argument for the `class` parameter.